# Node.js problem using cluster and socket together

Tags: express, socket.io, cluster-computing

I don't know how to make clusters and socket.io work together. This is the part where clustering is implemented:

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;

    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {

    const app = express();
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    //more stuff
    app.post('/PDF', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
        //more stuff
        io.emit('status', 'Evaluating resources to be downloaded...');
    });
    //more stuff

    server.listen(8081, function () { })
}
```

It does what it's supposed to do... except that socket doesn't work anymore. I keep getting errors like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Rw3DSIP.png)

The warning ones popped out of nowhere... I haven't seen them yesterday. But I don't think it's that important and I can live with it. But I can't live without the sockets. Any help is greatly appreciated.